# Problems with javascript not loading on datetime picker in asp .net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the bootstrap datetime picker. I don't think the JavaScript get's loaded when the page is running. Here is the script that i try to run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#inputNewPublicationDate').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'dk'
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the textbox/input box that I want the date picker to be related to.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='inputNewPublicationDate'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using a masterpage if that is relevant for this problem. Can some one explained to me what I am doing wrong? Here is the generated HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
    Euro Poultry
</title><script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" /><link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="Content/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="Content/MenuCss.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="Content/MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /><link href="Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/da.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" /></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="NewProduct" id="ctl01">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="TohYngYAQpCAII8RpuQnEalPl/MTArnSEh+ZpM9u8IM0qp+pydvAXRs1biEQdGMzypAlutTdOoQBFlApZ5P0jplQl6tY3em/XaDxCPoZLIUpPnQP/EJu8oNhT1EGKGTU/mY5b/S/GvhXA3nzCXGnQ37DOu9qDZwMxP3xDCwjFxTwNQux/jF9ZH/K24q0Fmgo7cpJALpuVCgmiBZ8nxTPpA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['ctl01'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.ctl01;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script src="/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax-framework på klientsiden blev ikke indlæst.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/bundles/WebFormsJs?v=AAyiAYwMfvmwjNSBfIMrBAqfU5exDukMVhrRuZ-PDU01" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="E6B80599" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="ziT0MWsXfU8bZf+HxgsyZxmvTOEWqLQAAVF2jCik7SvdOA/hstIfA8BYa8FfUczfqC2x1DvTsx1lx8eC0mAvo2idOZKBotnAxZyCCfL95qaIB3oeDzaq8WPooYr8Erpv" />
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl16', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>



        <div class="MenuBody">
            <a href="Overview.aspx">
                <div class="MenuBrand">
                    <p>EP</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="AllProducts.aspx">
                <div class="MenuBtn hvr-underline-from-left">
                    <p>Produkter</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="NewProduct.aspx">
                <div class="MenuBtn hvr-underline-from-left">
                    <p>Nyt Produkt</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="menuUnderLine">
        </div>




        <div class="Content fullscreen">

    <div class="newProductWrapper">

        <div class="myRow">
            <div class="mediumCol">
                <div class="myRow">
                    <div class="mediumCol title">
                        <span id="MainContent_lblNewGtin">GTIN - Global Trade Item Number</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="myRow">
                    <div class="mediumCol">
                        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtNewGtin" type="text" id="MainContent_txtNewGtin" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mediumCol">
                <div class="myRow">
                    <div class="mediumCol title">
                        <span id="MainContent_lblNewTargetMarket">Landekode for Target Market</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mediumCol">
                        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddNewTargetMarket" id="MainContent_ddNewTargetMarket" class="form-control">

</select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="myRow">

            <div class="smallCol">
                <div class="myRow">
                    <div class="smallCol title">
                        <span id="MainContent_Label1">Start gyldighedsdato</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smallCol">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='inputNewEffectiveDate'>
                                <input id="txtNewEffectiveDate" type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="smallCol">
                <div class="myRow">
                    <div class="smallCol title">
                        <span id="MainContent_lblNewPublicationDate">Publikationsdato</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smallCol">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='inputNewPublicationDate'>
                                <input id="txtNewPublicationDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon" style="z-index: 200;">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#txtNewEffectiveDate').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'da'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#inputNewPublicationDate').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'da'
            });
        });
    </script>


        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure that your script initialising the datetimepicker is called after your jQuery script is loaded

Comment: .. and you have included bootstrap js

Comment: Take a look at your generated HTML: firstly if your scripts are loaded in the correct order: 1- jQuery 2- Bootstrap 3- The script you attempt to use `datetimepicker`. And secondly, see if the generated `#datetimepicker2` is maintaining that `id`, because sometimes ASP.NET changes it.

Comment: Also you can visit here and see the source code of the widget. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ . Also give  id='datetimepicker2' to the input filed not to the div.

Comment: i cant seem to get i to work by trying any of this. just a sec and im am going to post the generated html

Comment: @KevinJensen are you using bootstrap datetime picker, also is `dk` for Danish?

Comment: @Shehary Yes it is bootstrap date time picker from here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ Yes dk is for danish, but i can see that is not an option so i have changed that to english

Comment: @KevinJensen then the locale is wrong `dk` it should be `da` check here http://jsfiddle.net/wte3yxef/9/

Comment: @KevinJensen also you are missing couple of lib , moment.js, and locale for `da`

Comment: @KevinJensen even if you go with `en` you need `moment.js` for bootstrapdatetime picker to work

Comment: If you give the id to div then the date picker is always highlighted. Here is the Js fiddel example: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/dfo2veqc/

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman it's jQuery datetime picker not bootstrap datetimepicker which OP is trying to use. there is huge huge difference

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman now i get an error that says, datetimepicker is not a function?

Comment: I can't find `id="datetimepicker2"` anywhere in your rendered HTML

Comment: if you are working in simple file or local host then add http:// before each "//code.jquery.........." . Because in local file system with out http:// the browser cannot retrive the .Js file from the cdn.....

Comment: Also please reformat your question. Any one can downvote it. Because you told your problem with id="datetimepicker2". But second portion of the code used id='inputNewPublicationDate' :)

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman I have tried to put http:// before the code.jquery files but it still says that its not a function. i also get an error that says **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: You can see this:https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization .. And the 404 error means server can not find some of your other resources which loading code is placed before jquery loading code.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman now i am not getting any errors. But it is still not firing for some reason

Comment: Also you can use Jquery date time picker.